# Custom UIView in Interface Builder / Cross Platform

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a control library for iOS and Mac OS.  It's implemented as follows:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustonControl : UIControl
...
@end

#else

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyCustomControl : NSControl
...
@end

#endif
```

This works fine if I build the control in the view controller.  If I try to use Interface Builder, I can never set the UIView's Custom Class to MyCustomControl.  It shows up in the list and I can type it in, but if I focus something else and then focus the view again, the custom class has reverted back to UIView.

I've implemented initFromCoder in both implementations, just to make sure it wasn't that.

Any way of fixing this?  Is it IB being weird or should I define my class in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the custom class to your control because the custom class needs to be a subclass of UIView/NSView, whereas UIControl/NSControl are parents of UIView/NSView. You should change your definitions to

```
@interface MyCustomControl : UIView
...
@interface MyCustomControl : NSView
```